# ckeditor insertHtml() form jquery.load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#x_img" ).load( "../x_img.php?id=123" );


$("#x_img").delegate("img", "click",function() {
       CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertHtml('<img src="'+$(this).attr('alt')+'" />');
});
</script>
```

I have a function that loads images (x_img) for user use. x_img jq.load in this page.

Using this code I click the image to insert, which works OK. But, I cannot get the image `src` value!

CKEditor shows this: `<img src="undefined" />`

Is the problem that the image is on another page?

Comment: So you're setting the `alt` attribute of the image as the source of the tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your editor is showing

`<img src="undefined" />`

then

```
$(this).attr('alt')
```

will return `undefined` because the `img` node doesn't have an `alt='something'` attribute. This `undefined` is then being concated into your `img`'s `src` attribute.

Try changing your image tag to something like the following:

```
<img alt="/images/funtimesatthebeach.jpg" />
```

Then, your code should load the image at `/images/funtimesatthebeach.jpg`.